# Fetching category based XML Feeds

Tags: rss, wordpress, feeds, cms, xml

I am working on a web app for which I have to fetch RSS feeds for a specific website. 
Initially I was using Yahoo pipes but later on I found Yahoo pipes can not filter feeds as per categories.

So instead, searched for how to get specific tag/category based feeds and found;

> For example: the URL for any posts tagged with WordPress on this site
>   is:
>
> http:// thedeadone.net/tag/wordpress/
>
> The non-fancy-permalink version would be:
>
> http:// thedeadone.net/?tag=wordpress
>
> Now, to get an RSS feed for that tag you change the URL like this for
>   fancy permalinks:
>
> http:// thedeadone.net/tag/wordpress/feed
>
> Change the non-fancy permalink like this:
>
> http:// thedeadone.net/?tag=wordpress&feed=rss2

Now, the problem is that it gives category based feeds just for WordPress. The feed I have, I do not even know how can I check if the feed is of WordPress CMS or some other. And if it is of some other, how can I get the category based feed?

For example [this feed](http://www.atvn.org/rss.xml); I do not know how to get category based feeds from this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The categorized RSS feed links might differ from site to site, CMS to CMS. For the given website, I did a quick google search for [`filetype:xml site:atvn.org`](https://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=filetype%3axml%20site%3aatvn.org)(click it). It seems they have feed links like this -

```
www.atvn.org/alumni/rss.xml
www.atvn.org/blogs/rss.xml
www.atvn.org/user/rss.xml
www.atvn.org/news/2012/rss.xml
```

etc.

From the search results, this site seems to be running on Drupal. You can check Drupal's RSS feed mechanisms. [Some examples here](http://learnbythedrop.com/drop/45), more you can search.